Convergence of a matrix coefficient

Let $x \in SL\left(2, \mathbb{R}\right)$, and define a function
$$
\phi\left(x\right) = \left\langle\,{ \pi\left(x\right)\xi,\xi}\,\right\rangle
$$
where $\left(\pi,H\right)$ is a unitary representation with $\xi \in H$.
Suppose
$$
a = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda & 0
\\
0 & \lambda^{-1}
\end{bmatrix},\quad
\left(\lambda_{i}\right)_{i\ \in\ I}\,\,
\mbox{is a net in}\ \mathbb{R}\ \mbox{converging to}\ 0
$$
and $\lambda_i \neq 0\,\, \forall i \in I$.
Set
$g_i =
\begin {bmatrix} 0 & \lambda_i^{-1}
\\
\lambda_i & 0
\end{bmatrix}$.
Suppose we are given that
$\phi\left(a\right)= \lim_{i}\phi\left(g_{i}\right)$.
We then need to show that
$\phi\left(a\right) = \left\langle\,{\pi\left(a\right)\xi,\xi}\,\right\rangle = \left\vert\left\vert\,{\xi}\,\right\vert\right\vert^{2}$.
That means, we need to show that
$\lim_{i}\phi\left(g_{i}\right) = \left\vert\left\vert\,{\xi}\,\right\vert\right\vert^{2}$.

I do not know why that should be true:
$$
\mbox{Is it obvious from how}\ g_{i}\ \mbox{is defined ?.}
$$
